# Scanning a directory and processing specific files simultaneously with fork in C

Tags: c, process, fork, ls

My goal is to implement an "ls" function so that I can scan through a specified  directory and look for .csv files to process. My thinking right now is to create a child process using fork() each time a csv file is detected using the ls function but I am very confused on how to do this. I have read the fork() page on geeksforgeeks and if I call fork for every time a csv file is detected, the child processes would keep multiplying by 2? And would I have to wrap my entire processing code in the fork statement? If I waited for the each child process to complete before creating another child, that wouldn't be multiprocessing. I'm still learning C and I'm finding it hard to grasp how the fork function actually works. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The child process created by the `fork` call should not continue searching the directory, it should process the file and then `exit`. There are probably millions of example of how to use `fork` all over the Internet (including Stack Overflow), if you just search a little.

Comment: Why would you want to fork a new process per file?  That's an expensive way of doing whatever it is you're up to.  If the purpose is to exercise you using `fork()`, that's one thing; if you're trying to do serious work, it is another thing altogether.  If the child processes exec `ls`, then there won't be an explosion of processes — they won't multiply by 2 each time.

Comment: After you call fork, you check the return value. If it returns `0` you're in the child, you call the function that processes the file and exit without continuing the loop. If it returns non-zero you're still in the parent process, so you continue scanning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic structure should look something like this:

```
while(d = readdir(fd) {
    if (iscsv(d->d_name)) {
        int pid = fork();
        switch(pid) {
        case 0: // Child process
            process_csv(d->d_name);
            exit(0);
            break;
        case -1: // Error
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
            break;
        default: // Parent
            printf("Forked PID %d to process %s\n", pid, d->d_name);
    }
}
```

The return value of `pid` is used to distinguish whether you're continuing in the parent or child. The child processes the file and exits, the parent continues looping. So you don't keep doubling processes (known as a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)), because only the original parent keeps looping and forking.

Comment: Do in need to add a wait() system call to make sure the child process is done running before forking another child or is it not necessary?

Comment: It's not necessary if you want all the processing to be done concurrently. That's the reason to do it in child processes, isn't it?